# How do you resolve issues with named pipes?

Tags: unix, shell, named-pipes, svm

I have a binary program* which takes the contents of a supplied file, processes it, and prints the result on the screen through stdout. For an automation script, I would like to use a named pipe to send data to this program and process the output myself. After trying to get the script to work I realized that there is an issue with the binary program accepting data from the named pipe. To illustrate the problem I have outlined several tests using the unix shell.

1. It is easy to show that the program works by processing an actual data file.

   ```
   $ binprog file.txt > output.txt
   ```

   This will result in output.txt containing the processed information from file.txt.
2. The named pipe (pipe.txt) works as seen by this demonstration.

   ```
   $ cat pipe.txt > output.txt
   $ cat file.txt > pipe.txt
   ```

   This will result in output.txt containing the data from file.txt after it has been sent through the pipe.
3. When the binary program is reading from the named pipe instead of the file, things do not work correctly.

   ```
   $ binprog pipe.txt > output.txt
   $ cat file.txt > pipe.txt
   ```

   In this case output.txt contains no data even after cat and binprog terminate. Using top and ps, I can see binprog "running" and seemingly  doing work. Everything executes with no errors.

Why is there no output produced by binprog in this third example?

 
What are some things I could try to get this working?

[*] The program in question is svm-scale from [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). I chose to generalize the examples to keep them clean and simple.

Comment: If you start binprog before you start to write to the named pipe it is possible that when binprog read()s the "file" (pipe.txt), it gets zero bytes out and, without regards to the actuall error code, just exits. What happens if you ran cat before binprog?

Comment: Antti.huima, I tried starting the process which pipes data into the pipe first and the binprog process after and it makes no difference--the exact same thing happens.

Comment: Don't you have to run 'cat pipe.txt > output.txt' in background?  Similarly with 'binprog'?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the program will work with a pipe?  If it needs random access to the input file it won't work.  The program will get an error whenever it tries to seek in the input file.

If you know the program is designed to work with pipes, and you're using bash, you can use process substitution to avoid having to explicitly create the named pipe.

```
binprog <(cat file.txt) > output.txt
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it should work with a pipe and even after it executes it doesn't produce any errors nor does it crash. The substitution idea is interesting but ultimately won't work for my script.

Answer (score 1):

Does binprog also accept input on stdin?  If so, this might work for you.

```
cat pipe.txt | binprog > output.txt
cat file.txt > pipe.txt
```

**Edit:** Briefly scanned the manpage for svm-scale.  Give this a whirl instead:

```
cat pipe.txt | svm-scale - > output.txt
```

Comment: No it doesn't accept input from stdin.

Nothing like that was in my man page, I tried it anyway and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If `binprog` is not working well with anything other than a terminal as an input, maybe you need to give it a (pseudo-)terminal (pty) for its input.  That is harder to organize, but the `expect` program is one way of doing that relatively easily.  There are discussions of programming with pty's in 
[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739) by W Richard Stevens and Stephen A Rago, and in [Advanced Unix Programming, 2nd Edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543) by Marc J Rochkind.

Something else to look at is the output of `truss` or `strace` or the local equivalent.  These programs log all the system calls made by a process.  On Solaris, I'd run:

```
truss -o binprog.truss binprog
```

interactively, and see what it does.  Then I'd try it with i/o redirection, and then with i/o redirection from the named pipe; there may be some significant differences between what it does, or you may see the system call that is hanging.  If you see forks in the truss log file, you would need to add a '`-f`' flag to follow children.